# Telegram API: How to make message history for new group users visible

Tags: telegram, telethon, telegram-api

I want to make message history for new group users visible. For now I have managed to find [channels.togglePreHistoryHidden](https://core.telegram.org/method/channels.togglePreHistoryHidden) method in the API but it takes channel as an argument, not a group. There is no similar method for groups. Moreover, as far as I know there is no such option to hide message history for channels in telegram so i'm a bit confused. Could anyone explain me how should I do this. Code snippet in `telethon` would be greate.

Answer (score 0):

You can safely run `channels.togglePreHistoryHiddenRequest` on a supergroup to achieve what you want; just disregard the type hint, as it['s generated](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/concepts/full-api.html) from [the documentation provided by Telegram](https://core.telegram.org/method/channels.togglePreHistoryHidden) and the input type is incorrect even at the source:

```py
await client(
    functions.channels.TogglePreHistoryHiddenRequest(
        channel=123456789,  # The ID of your supergroup
        enabled=False,
    )
)
```